# Getting "sec" attribute directly from MongoDate Object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm returning data from a MongoDb query

```
 {
    "site": "def",
    "ip": "123.0.0.2",
    "context": "home",
    "uri": "could-bit",
    "t": {
        "sec": 1516731260,
        "usec": 742000
    }
 }'
```

and I want to eliminate the t Object attributes, and leave the "sec" attribute only.

I tried to do so with

```
$db->$collection->find(['t' => array('$gt' => $gte, '$lt' => $lte)], ['site' => true, 'ip' => true, 'uri' => true, 'context' => true, 't.sec' => true, '_id' => false])
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You should use aggregation framework for that

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {   $match: { t: { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            site: 1,
            ip: 1,
            context: 1,
            uri: 1,
            sec: "$t.sec"
        }
    }
])
```

Where `$match` will be exactly your filtering condition as it is in your `find`.

Comment: Not working :/, tried :       $data = $db->$collection->aggregate(
                [
                    ['$match' => ['t' => ['$gte' => $gte, '$lte' => $lte ]] ],
                    ['$project' => ['site' => 1, 'ip' => 1, 'uri' => 1, 't' => '$t.sec', 'context' => 1, '_id' => 0]]
                ],  array('cursor' => new \stdClass())
             );

Comment: @AmiineBenkeroum you didn't mention it but I guess it's PHP so you should look at examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php . My query is working in Mongo shell so it should only be a matter of language syntax.